# COALESCE() function with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have three tables,

- **comments**: id, user_id, place_id, text
- **places**: id, name
- **users**: id, name

I'd like to show a list of all the places with a list of all the users who commented on that place.

```
McDonalds  Jill, Suzy, Bob
Walmart    Fred, Joe, Suzy, Larry
Library    Joe, Suzy
...
```

I am trying to use the `coalesce` function to achieve this but I am running into trouble. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT places.name, COALESCE(users.name+",")
FROM comments
JOIN places
ON comments.place_id = places.id
WHERE user_id = users.id
GROUP BY places.name
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which RDBMS please? `COALESCE` returns the first non-null value. Possibly you are thinking of MySql `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: Using SQL Server 2005 for Windows... for a class with outdated textbook

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5981860/314291) at options on mimicking `GROUP_CONCAT` in sql server. e.g. using `FOR XML PATH` + `STUFF`

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and possibly table creation script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this !

Using Coalesce is not relevant here,try using [STUFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) with [XML PATH('')](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)

```
SELECT t1.name, 
STUFF(
(
SELECT ',' + [places.name] FROM comments
JOIN places
ON comments.place_id = places.id
WHERE user_id = users.id
GROUP BY places.name
for xml path('')
),1,1,'') as t1 from table <group by>
```